# What is the quantum circuit complexity of a multi-control Y-gate with n control bits and 1 output bit?

Tags: quantum-gate, complexity-theory

It is known that many multicontrol quantum gates consist of sets of elementary gates, and there seems to be no authoritative way to give the complexity of such multicontrol quantum gates. So using one of the multicontrol quantum Y gates in the title as a case study, please either prove it mathematically or cite a more authoritative reference on its complexity. It is required to give an expression for its scaling with the number of quantum bits.

Comment: Why would it be much different than the cost of CCCC..X, which has already been well studied?  Also your comment about something being "required" makes it sound like you copied this from a homework assignment, but you haven't indicated what work, if any, you have done.

Comment: Sorry this isn't homework, I'm just keeping track of the latest authoritative papers on this aspect of CCCCC...X(Y/Z). I am not aware that its complexity has been fully investigated, could you please show the authoritative references that you are aware of?

Comment: Have you seen this https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11513

Comment: Sorry, but although it is a relatively new article, it is a preprint and has not yet been unanimously approved by its peers. I have been pursuing prestigious journals such as Nature or Science, which would give my research more credibility.

Comment: I don’t think the authors of the linked paper ever intended to publish it. You could uses Beverland et al., to which this paper responds and which is published. Otherwise good luck!